# Odd imagemagick convert behavior

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I'm seeing some really strange behavior w/the imagemagick convert command.  I have an image raw.gif.  I then run:

```
convert raw.gif convert.png
```

And the output in convert.png appears to be shrunk and shifted.  However, if I run:

```
convert raw.gif convert.jpg
convert convert.jpg convert_jpg.png
```

All images are below.

convert_jpg.png looks exactly like raw.gif which I would expect.  I am sure I am missing something obvious but can't figure it out for the life of me.

raw.gif
[image: raw.gif]

convert.png
[image: convert.png]

convert.jpg
[image: convert.jpg]

convert_jpg.png
[image: convert_jpg.png]

Comment: Works fine for me (ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-06-28 Q16).  Assuming that GIF didn't change when you attached it?  Try saving the GIF from your question and converting it to double-check.

Comment: random thoughts: multi-frame gif with the second frame being all black? alpha channel produced from .gif transparent color?

Comment: @paddy - Just tried it and still doesn't work.  I'm running a much older version (6.2.8 10/06/10 Q16) but I've never had an issue before w/this command.  I'll try to update and see what happens.